# If I mess up the EFI System Partition, will Mac OS X be unbootable?

Tags: startup, partition, dual-boot, efi

I forgot to make a backup of my EFI System Partition (ESP) and  have installed grub onto it.

If I happen to accidentally mess up the partition, will OS X be bootable? If not, how would I restore the EFI System Partition without having a backup?

Comment: OS X will still be bootable. See [rEfit Myths & Facts About Intel Macs](http://refit.sourceforge.net/myths/) for more extensive explanation, including Grub specific Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it happens you mess it up, you can [download it from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1237).

EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Macs

This article lists firmware updates that were released for Intel-based Macs. They update the firmware that originally shipped from the factory. If your computer isn't on this list, then you don't need an update to the factory firmware.